# ROS-hydro-opencv2 fails to install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS (ros-hydro-desktop-full), and every time it gets stuck at the same specific place:

```
Err http: //packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-hydro-opencv2 amd64
2.4.6-3precise-20140130-1852-+0000   Connection failed [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
```

I try pinging the reported IP and it works fine.
I have followed the exact same steps as mentioned in the Installation Guide- and the most of the other packages get downloaded fine. This one, and a few more don't:

```
Err http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libboost1.46-dev amd64
1.46.1-7ubuntu3   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

Err http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main texlive-binaries amd64 2009-11ubuntu2
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Err http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libicu-dev amd64 4.8.1.1-3ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

Err http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libicu-dev amd64
4.8.1.1-3ubuntu0.1   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
```

It exits with "Unable to correct missing packages." Same story if I try installing these separately.

Could someone please help?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 (LTS), 64-bit, installed on a Windows partition using Wubi. I have updated and upgraded (many times, actually).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138016/ros-hydro-opencv2-fails-to-install/) by [a-Jays](https://answers.ros.org/users/13081/a-jays/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're having trouble connecting to multiple unrelated servers with the same error it suggest that you either have a local configuration problem or a problem with your connection.

This does not appear to be a ROS related question but a generic apt problem I suggest that you try a resource like stack overflow.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0